# React PropType is not giving error when isRequired is used

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I am trying to learn React but the `PropTypes` even when used with `isRequired` is not throwing any error. Am i doing something wrong.

The code is like this

```
<div id="root"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15.6.2/prop-types.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">

    function SayHello(props) {
        return (
            <div>
                Hello {props.firstName} {props.lastName}!
            </div>
        )
    }

    SayHello.propTypes = {
        firstName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        lastName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<SayHello />, document.getElementById('root'))

</script>
```

Shouldn't this throw an `error` or a `warning` when `firstName` and `lastName` isn't sent.

Thus making those two props mandatory similar to this.

```
<SayHello firstName="John" lastName="Doe" />
```

I am getting no error or warning on my browser.

Comment: Hi, have you checked the browser console? proptypes throws errors there, it doesn't show anything on the actual browser view port..

Comment: @bullettrain, I am checking the browser console only. Even a babel warning about `in-browser Babel transformer` pops up but nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be some issue with minified version of proptypes.

Change your

`https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15.6.2/prop-types.min.js`

to

`https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15.6.2/prop-types.js`

You will get warning Failed proptype.

Comment: Thank you. But shouldn't the minified versions have the same code but with no comments and line breaks? I know about `jQuery` and their versions but here?

Comment: It's my pleasure. Yes, minified version must provide same functionality by removing unnecessary code.  In this case there might be some different issue.

Answer (score 2):

here is the working solution https://codesandbox.io/s/ymorp9y17v

```
import * as PropTypes from "prop-types";

const SayHello = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      Hello {props.firstName} {props.lastName}!
    </div>
  );
};

SayHello.propTypes = {
  firstName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  lastName: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default SayHello;
```

Comment: `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';` is fine. There's no need for the `*`

Comment: Yep, It throws an error. But, What was wrong with my code in the first place? Also my code still does not throw an error.

Comment: I updated the snippet: https://codesandbox.io/s/ymorp9y17v. I don't exactly know why force `*` import, but my IDE says: Default export is not declared in imported module

Comment: It still didn't throw an error. I changed the `unpkg` versions and it works.

Answer (score 1):

## EDIT

@JS Engine correct, change PropTypes from production version to development version.

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15.6.2/prop-types.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">

    function SayHello(props) {
        return (
            <div>
                Hello {props.firstName} {props.lastName}!
            </div>
        )
    }

    SayHello.propTypes = {
        firstName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        lastName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<SayHello />, document.getElementById('root'))

</script>
```